# Path alias inheritance in tsconfig for Angular/NX Project

Tags: angular, tsconfig, nrwl-nx

I wonder if it is possible in a Angular/NX project to have global path aliasses in tsconfig -> compilerOptions -> paths and additionally local path aliasses in each project which are inherited with extends? Or are the global path aliasses overwritten with local app path aliasses?

If they are overwritten would that mean that I have to have duplicate definitions in each app to reference for example libs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you delcare local path aliases, global one will be overwritten. I have hard time with it.

So if you have tsconfig in one of your modules that extend your global tsconfig:

```
  "extends": "../../../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
     "paths":{
       // override all paths from global tsconfig.json
       }
   }
```

If you make extend and **don't** include paths, all aliases from global tsconfig will be available.

Comment: thanks. This just saved me hours)